# load CSV- node created for NULL value

Tags: null, neo4j

Hi I'm a real beginner and playing around with a CSV file as follows , but keep getting a node created for the NULL Food nodes. Any hints?

```
Animals,Food,Cost,Description
dogs,dogfood,cheap,fluffy
dogs,meat,expensive,dirty
cats,catfood,expensive,fluffy
cats,,expensive,white
cats,,expensive,dirty
rabbit,cabbage,cheap,fluffy
rabbit,lettuce,cheap,black
```

I use query:-

```
LOAD CSV  WITH HEADERS FROM "file:Q:/ASSISTANT TO TECH MANAGER/Neo4j Data/test.csv" 
AS line
WITH line 
WHERE line.Food IS NOT NULL
MERGE(animals:Animals{name:line.Animals})
MERGE(food:Food{name:line.Food}) 
MERGE(cost:Cost{cost:line.Cost})
MERGE(description:Description{description:line.Description})
MERGE (animals)-[e:EAT]->(food)-[c:COSTS]->(cost)
MERGE (animals)-[l:LOOK]->(description)
RETURN e,c,l
```

Answer (score 3):

Paul,

An empty field is still a field. It's not null. If you still want to create the other nodes, your query should be something like:

```
LOAD CSV  WITH HEADERS FROM "file:Q:/ASSISTANT TO TECH MANAGER/Neo4j Data/test.csv" 
AS line
MERGE(animals:Animals{name:line.Animals})
MERGE(cost:Cost{cost:line.Cost})
MERGE(description:Description{description:line.Description})
MERGE (animals)-[l:LOOK]->(description)
WITH line, animals, cost, l 
WHERE line.Food <> ''
MERGE(food:Food{name:line.Food}) 
MERGE (animals)-[e:EAT]->(food)-[c:COSTS]->(cost)
RETURN e,c,l
```

Grace and peace,

Jim